# python decorator NameError

Tags: python, decorator

```
class AUC:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.function(*args, **kwargs)
        print('-> AUC Score {}'.format(roc_auc_score(y_test, predictions)))

            
class AccuracyScore:

    def __init__(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
        self.self = self
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.y_train = y_train
        self.X_test = X_test
        self.y_test = y_test
         
    @AUC
    def DT(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
        clf_dt = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=2023)
        clf_dt = clf_dt.fit(X_train, y_train)
        predictions = clf_dt.predict(X_test)
        accuracy = clf_dt.score(X_test, y_test)
        print('DT Accuracy:', accuracy)
```

hello, I got "NameError: name 'predictions' is not defined".
Actually I use decorator first time..
how could I revise the code?

Thank you.

I want to get AUC score for each machine learning algorithms using decorator.

Comment: I don't understand why you want a decorator when you could just move the `print('-> AUC . . .` line into the function.

Comment: Add self to self.predictions.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to update your code like this:

```py
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

class AUC:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        predictions = self.function(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the decorated function and get the predictions
        auc_score = roc_auc_score(kwargs['y_test'], predictions)
        print('-> AUC Score: {}'.format(auc_score))
        return predictions  # Return the predictions to be used by the decorated function


class AccuracyScore:
    def __init__(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.y_train = y_train
        self.X_test = X_test
        self.y_test = y_test

    @AUC
    def DT(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
        clf_dt = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=2023)
        clf_dt = clf_dt.fit(X_train, y_train)
        predictions = clf_dt.predict(X_test)
        accuracy = clf_dt.score(X_test, y_test)
        print('DT Accuracy:', accuracy)
        return predictions  # Return the predictions to be used by the AUC decorator


# Example usage
X_train = ...
y_train = ...
X_test = ...
y_test = ...

accuracy_score = AccuracyScore(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
predictions = accuracy_score.DT(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
```

You have to return `predictions` in the decorated function.